# Plot a table in Rmarkdown beamer with stargazer

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am tryng to plot the summary of a regression in my beamer rmarkdown presentation. Using the stargazer function, I do this

````
```{r, echo = T , comment =  "" , message=FALSE, warning=FALSE }
regra_taylor_0 <- dynlm(selic ~ lag(selic,-1) + desvio + hiato, data=data_estimacao_ts)

```

```{r, echo = F , comment =  "" , message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}

stargazer(regra_taylor_0 )


```
````

But the result in the presetation is like this

```
% Table created by stargazer v.5.2.2 by Marek Hlavac, Harvard University. E-mail: hlavac at fas.harvard.edu
% Date and time: qua, jun 20, 2018 - 14:47:05
\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering
\caption{}
\label{}
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lc}
\\[-1.8ex]\hline
\hline \\[-1.8ex]
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textit{Dependent variable:}} \\
\cline{2-2}
\\[-1.8ex] & selic \\
\hline \\[-1.8ex]
lag(selic, -1) & 0.962$^{***}$ \\
& (0.036) \\
& \\
```

Please help

Comment: Now,  some table incomplete apear. But before the table I have this "% Table created by stargazer v.5.2.2 by Marek Hlavac, Harvard
University. E-mail: hlavac at fas.harvard.edu % Date and time: qua,
jun 20, 2018 - 15:04:18"

Comment: @eipi10 Like this? ## Resultadp
```{r, echo = T , comment =  "" , message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, results="asis" , xtable.comment = FALSE}

stargazer(regra_taylor_0 )


```

Comment: I do this and it is not working

Comment: ```{r, echo = F , comment =  "" , message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, results="asis"}
options(xtable.comment = FALSE)
stargazer(regra_taylor_0 , font.size = 'footnotesize' )

```

Comment: And the size parameter is not working too. Do you know how to resize the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a minimal example that demonstrates how to get the desired stargazer output and also to remove the stargazer comment message:

````
---
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
# You can set chunk options globally so you don't have to repeat them in every chunk
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE)

library(stargazer)
```

```{r, results='asis'}
stargazer(lm(mpg ~ wt, data=mtcars), header=FALSE)
```

If you want to change and option for a specific chunk, you can do add a chunk option
like echo=FALSE.


```{r, results='asis', echo=FALSE}
stargazer(lm(mpg ~ wt + hp + vs, data=mtcars), header=FALSE)
```

```{r, results='asis'}
# Change the font size with the font.size argument. See the help for size options
stargazer(lm(mpg ~ wt + hp + vs, data=mtcars), header=FALSE, font.size = "scriptsize")
```
````

Comment: Ok, it is working. Do you know how to reduze the size of the table?